# right understanding about nested view scope?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have created nested backbone view like this.

```
var parentView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    el: 'body',
    template: Html,
    events: { 'click #seemore': 'seeMore' },
    initialize:function () { this.render(); },
    render:function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template);

        //here I am creating nested view
        this.childView = new ChildView();
    }
    seeMore:function (e) {
        //here I am calling nested view's method/function
        this.childView.getData();
        return false;
    },
})
```

If I create view like this, Is this bed practice? means my child view is come under parent class scope, Here I just using single method of child class, So, I think why I am giving whole object/class in parent class scope?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not a bad practice. You can initialize child view under a parent view.

Comment: thanks @MaheshSapkal, I have doubt about variable scope. my child view's all variables comes under parent view scope. Is this utilized more memory?

Comment: It is not a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't the child view contain the see more button and gets the data itself?

Comment: hi @OferHaber, In above situation, my parent view is a collection of child view. so "See more" button should come in parent view.